# SymmetricDS: filesync status in sym_outgoing_batch

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I have used filesync to sync to specific node for quite some time. 
Recently I noticed that

1. Some node has channel filesync_reload auto created in outgoing batches and the status is always LD even after the file has already been sync to target. In log it always show retrying batch.
2. Some of the nodes has outgoing status NE and the files are not synced to target.

May I know what is the reason behind and how should I fix it? Can I manually update all the status to OK ?

Comment: Is there possible that after a file is created then deleted within few seconds, so symmetricds track the file change but when it want to start sync, it cannot find the file, so the filesync_reload is auto created and forever LD ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ssh to the target node and check the logs which will tell why the outgoing batch at the source is failing. Expect to have a stack trace with a message explaining what has gone wrong.

Comment: I know why the NE is not able to sync. It is because some target node has comment off the filesync enabled. But I still noticed some filesync_reload for certain store has been inserted into outgoing batches. Why is this happening ?

Comment: NE is NEw. Reload usually happens when a new node is registered and it requests the initial load. Check which node is targeted with these batches.

Comment: It is existing nodes and always LD

Comment: targeting nodes then should be returning an error message or an acknowledgement. the best is to "go" to targeting nodes and check the logs

Comment: It did not return any error, I updated the LD to OK to remove the unwanted batches. Now it is ok not creating any reload batches.

Comment: ERROR happen again where file did not sync to target, and cause other data synchronization issue. Can I separate out file sync and normal data sync to two different engine so it won't interrupt each other ?

Failed to execute FILE_XTRCT for node 000021 and channel default StackTraceKey.init [SqlException:3677278039]

Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object

Comment: Either the limit of created connections has been reached or for some other reason symmetricDs can not open a new connection to the DB

Comment: What you mean by limit of created connections has been reached ? Do you mean I cannot have 2 engine files to represent corp ?

Comment: "Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object" -- symmetricDs engine can not get an open connection to "talk" to the database. No more than one engine (properties) file per DB should be defined!

Comment: Can I define another DB just for filesync ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the same DB url, username & password shouldn't be in no more than one symmetric-ds.properties file

Comment: I wonder if I can change the port number to a different one example 31418. My firewall is off. But it still could not communicate using new port with new db

Comment: I put one more symmetricds folder and change the symmetric-server.properties file to different port number so that it work. It failed to install another instance as service. I'm thinking that by splitting data and file sync to two different symmetric instance might not solve the timeout and retry issue.